# Custom Scroll Bar for Div with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there a way to customize a scrollbar with only CSS that effects a specific div and not everything in the entire page?

I have found that I can use `::-webkit-scrollbar` In order to change the style of a scrollbar, but this affects every scrollbar on the page.

I'm looking for a purely CSS way of styling a specific scroll bar on the page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is. All you have to do is keep in mind that `::-webkit-scrollbar` is a pseudo-class, and as such, can be used like this:

```
div.foo::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
```

Comment: I having the issue . what is the div.foo ? what is div and what is foo ?