# Custom scrollbar using pure JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I want to create a customized scrollbar with pure CSS3 and JS. This should be done using div elements. Please avoid plugins and `overflow-scroll`. 
The content div may contain any element like `p`, `ul` or `image`.

I know how to move elements by using offset values. Do you have any ideas how to create such a scrollbar?

Comment: This may help you [scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a vertical scroll bar on an inner div contained in a fixed dimension outer div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235621/how-do-i-get-a-vertical-scroll-bar-on-an-inner-div-contained-in-a-fixed-dimensio)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338818/custom-scroll-bar-for-div-with-pure-css?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div

Comment: you asking to add styles to your scrollbar?

Comment: No,I wants to create a scrollbar without any plugin ,webkit,Pure css and javascript

Answer (score 0):

I know you said no plugins but you may want to check out the small function shown on this page which will provide what you're looking for:

http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/scrollbar/index.html

Basically, the code looks as so:

```
function makeScrollbar(content,scrollbar,handle,horizontal,ignoreMouse){
                var steps = (horizontal?(content.getScrollSize().x - content.getSize().x):(content.getScrollSize().y - content.getSize().y))
                var slider = new Slider(scrollbar, handle, {    
                    steps: steps,
                    mode: (horizontal?'horizontal':'vertical'),
                    onChange: function(step){
                        // Scrolls the content element in x or y direction.
                        var x = (horizontal?step:0);
                        var y = (horizontal?0:step);
                        content.scrollTo(x,y);
                    }
                }).set(0);
                if( !(ignoreMouse) ){
                    // Scroll the content element when the mousewheel is used within the 
                    // content or the scrollbar element.
                    $$(content, scrollbar).addEvent('mousewheel', function(e){  
                        e = new Event(e).stop();
                        var step = slider.step - e.wheel * 30;  
                        slider.set(step);                   
                    });
                }
                // Stops the handle dragging process when the mouse leaves the document body.
                $(document.body).addEvent('mouseleave',function(){slider.drag.stop()});
            }

            window.addEvent('domready', function(){             
                // -- first example, vertical scrollbar --
                makeScrollbar( $('content1'), $('scrollbar1'), $('handle1') );
                // -- second example, horizontal scrollbar --
                makeScrollbar( $('content2'), $('scrollbar2'), $('handle2'), true );
                // -- third example, horizontal and vertical scrollbars
                makeScrollbar( $('content3'), $('scrollbar3'), $('handle3'), false );
                makeScrollbar( $('content3'), $('scrollbar4'), $('handle4'), true, true );  
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

here by searching i just found amazing article to make custom scroll bar using css only.

```css
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(53, 198, 205, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
 <h1>Inset &amp; Customized WebKit Scrollbar</h1>

 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 
</body>
```

and here is the demo working of this code.

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sg4qsmso/1/)**

here where is found this wonderful thing i have given the reference link here

**[Reference Link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)**

Comment: Thank you, But it uses simply css

Comment: Using Both Javascript or jquery with css will be very useful

Comment: @Venkat it was just you can modify easily now if you want to affect the scrolling content's motions then you must try some scroll pluggins or you must analyze their code to work for you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @HimeshAadeshara